# Right sequence of functions

Tags: javascript, php

I try to call multiple functions on a `onChange` event (see index.php). The functions are working, but they are really slow. The sequence of the functions should be: `getPrice`, `getTax`, `getValues`, `getValues2`.

The script would work normal when that sequence was maintained.

```
getPrice      = 10.00
getTax        = 5.00   
              __________+
getValues     = 15.00 (total price)
```

The order of functions are now `getValues`, `getValues2`, `getPrice`, `getTax`. But this is not the right order. Now I get:

```
getPrice      = 10.00
getTax        = 5.00   
              __________+
getValues     = 0.00 (total price)
```

I need to perform change `getPrice` and `getTax` for the second time to make `getValues` the right calculation.

My question is. Is there a way to fix this? How can I run this script in a efficient and right way?

I use the following code:

index.php

```
<html>
<label>Quantity</label><br />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity1" id="quantity1" onChange='getPrice(this.value);getTax(this.value);getValues();getValues2()' placeholder="Quantity">
</html>
```

functions:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getPrice() {

    // getting the selected id in combo
    var selectedItem = jQuery('#product1 option:selected').val();

    // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'get.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'product1': selectedItem, 'quantity1' : jQuery('#quantity1').val()}, 
    success: function(response){
        // and put the price in text field
        jQuery('#price1').val(response);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    },
}); 
}
</script>

<script>
function getTax() {

    // getting the selected id in combo
    var selectedItem = jQuery('#product1 option:selected').val();

    // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'get11.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'product1': selectedItem, }, 
    success: function(response){
        // and put the price in text field
        jQuery('#tax1').val(response);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    },
}); 
}
</script>

<script>
function getValues(){
    var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("price1").value);
    var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("price2").value);
    var numVal3 = Number(document.getElementById("price3").value);
    var numVal5 = Number(document.getElementById("price4").value);

    var totalValue = numVal1 + numVal2+numVal3+numVal5;
    document.getElementById("total").value = totalValue;
}
</script>

<script>
function getValues2(){
    var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("tax1").value);
    var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("price1").value);

    var totalValue = numVal1 + numVal2;
    document.getElementById("lastprice").value = totalValue;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you define all of your functions (like `var getValues2 = function() { ... }`), then create a master function that calls all of your functions in order using the input data on successful reception of the first callback? That way you can ensure that all of your functions will be called in the desired order.

Comment: Chain them - call the appropriate (next) function from the 'onSuccess' of the previous.

Comment: getPrice and getTax are **asynchronous** ... therefore you need to wait for those to ajax calls to complete before you have a value for price and tax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is kinda software architecture problem. Why are you using particulary request for each action?

There are few better solutions:
1. Make a master controller that will fetch and compute data based on request's parameters
2. Fetch data while displaying a view, and then compute them in frontend using React for example (https://facebook.github.io/react/) 
3. As Jaromanda said you could chain the request - each in **done function** of previous request (https://laracasts.com/series/design-patterns-in-php/episodes/1)

```
<script>
function getPrice() {

    // getting the selected id in combo
    var selectedItem = jQuery('#product1 option:selected').val();

    // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'get.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'product1': selectedItem, 'quantity1' : jQuery('#quantity1').val()}, 
        success: function(response)
        {
            // and put the price in text field
            jQuery('#price1').val(response);

            getTax();
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        },
    }); 
}
</script>

<script>
function getTax() {

    // getting the selected id in combo
    var selectedItem = jQuery('#product1 option:selected').val();

    // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'get11.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'product1': selectedItem, }, 
        success: function(response){
            // and put the price in text field
            jQuery('#tax1').val(response);

                var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("price1").value);
                var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("price2").value);
                var numVal3 = Number(document.getElementById("price3").value);
                var numVal5 = Number(document.getElementById("price4").value);

                var totalValue = numVal1 + numVal2+numVal3+numVal5;
                document.getElementById("total").value = totalValue;

                var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("tax1").value);
                var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("price1").value);

                var totalValue = numVal1 + numVal2;
                document.getElementById("lastprice").value = totalValue;
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        },
    }); 
}
</script>
```